# Pass EditText data automatically to another activity EditText, only if it gets data in some pattern

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I am trying to pass data from web application to EditText using json.

Already i had completed the json part in my android app.Now i can able to send data from web application to MY app's EditText as

```
{
  "sender": "web app client",
  "command": {
    "type": "System.Clipboard",
    "text": "hello"
  }
}
```

Now i need to send this **"hello"** to the same app's another activity EditText automatically whenever it gets data like **"text":"data"** .

Answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Use data senders like "EVENT BUS" to activities. When a activity is subscribed to that specific event it will receive the data and can also unsubscribe while destroying.
Library Examples:
https://github.com/beworker/tinybus
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: hy first of all get the json object and check if there is text. if so then pass it with the intent to another activity and display it on the second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send String from first activity

**intent.putExtra("MyClass", value);**

To retrieve String in second Activity

**getIntent().getStringExtra("MyClass");**

When you send your text value either it is numerical or string

**Intent intent=new Intent() intent.putExtra("key",edittext.getText.toString())**

and then get This next to

**secondActivity 
getIntent.getStringExtra("key");**

you will get a String here set this string to Your EditText simple.

Comment: your question is quite confusing if you want to send obj u can use above code. what exactly u want to do explain your question!!

Comment: is it..! oh sorry..let me explain in detail.

Comment: i had EDITTEXT which contains both strings and integer values. but what i want to do is,only pass the integer values from that EDITTEXT to another activity EDITTEXT automatically. without my interaction after i entered.

Comment: apart from my question. I am asking in general brother. I had two activity and both activity has one EditText . I need to send from first activity EditText data to second activity EditText without a button click

Comment: i cannot upvote i tried already @kuldeep its saying 15 reputation record something like that..sorry brother